# Parent Relationship and Channel Category Archive

Tags: relationships, categories

I am still not 100% familiar with the newer relationships method added in 2.6 and I am wondering if I can get the **Channel Category Archive Tag** {exp:channel:category_archive} working with a parent relationship. It's for the table of contents of a monthly magazine, and I want the category heading and the entries listed below. The parent being the issue number.

Something like:

**Category**

- Article 1
- Article 2

**Category**

- Article 3
- Article 4

I've been playing with various combinations and no luck:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="print_editions" disable="pagination" limit="1"}

  {exp:channel:category_archive channel="articles" style="linear" show_empty="no" status="not closed"}
    {parents}
      <h2>{parents:categories}{category_name}{/parents:categories}</h2>
       <ul>
        {parents:entry_titles}
         <li>{parents:title}<li>    
        {/parents:entry_titles} 
       </ul>
    {/parents}
  {/exp:channel:category_archive}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain with EE relationships. I wrote up a good bit on the method we use here.

It was for product-buyers relationship paths, but is the same concept and I do certainly feel like you can get done what you need to here.

It can be done without the :search param in channel entries, I think under EE 2.6.... But it requires some well thought out plugin design.

Anyway, i'll leave this here and I do hope that it helps you.

https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/18229/1872

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I completely follow what you are after, but it looks like a nasty little ditty.

Without knowing how everything is set up, you might be able to try using embeds to toss the data around like you need it. I haven't tested any of this, but it looks like it would do what you need.

In your main template:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="print_editions" 
    disable="pagination" 
    limit="1"
}
    {parents}
        <h2>{parents:categories}{category_name}{/parents:categories}</h2>
        <ul>
            {embed="template_group/category-archive-data-template" 
                entryID="{entry_id}" 
                entryChannel="{channel}" 
                archiveChannel="articles"
            }
        </ul>
    {/parents}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then the 'category-archive-data-template' could have:

```
{exp:channel:category_archive 
    channel="{embed:archiveChannel}" 
    style="linear" 
    show_empty="no" 
    status="not closed"
}
    {embed="template_group/back-to-parent-relationship-data" 
        categoryID="{categories}{category_id}{/categories}" 
        entryChannel="{embed:entryChannel}" 
        entryID="{embed:entryID}"
    }
{/exp:channel:category_archive}
```

Then in the 'back-to-parent-relationship-data' you could do the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="{embed:entryChannel}" 
    entry_id="{embed:entryID}" 
    category="{embed:categoryID}" 
    disable="pagination"
}
    {parents}
        {parents:entry_titles}
            <li>{parents:title}<li>    
        {/parents:entry_titles} 
    {/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider it, but from a performance standpoint, I could likely do a couple channel entry loops filtered by category instead.

There is an easier way, I was close with the code I posted, so it can be done, it's just refining the way it's written.

For ref: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/category_archive.html