# How do I get all 'relatives' of a Playa entry?

Tags: playa

I have Playa field in a channel that is related to the same channel. So each entry in that channel can be related to another one in that channel. The problem is that to show all related entries for each entry, you have to check for children, parents, coparents and siblings and then filter out all duplicates...

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: The only "real" relations there are children and parents. Co-parents and siblings are 2nd degree relationships, as they relate to entries that relate to the current entry.

Comment: If it's a single field in a single channel, aren't you just looking for all the parents for a given entry X -- in other words just the other entries that have X selected in their playa field?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to simply skip over using playa to begin with.
I fought and fought with it too at a point.

Now I just do this: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/18229/1872

Hope it helps you.